# why the result of lsof | grep pid | wc -l and lsof -p pid |wc -l is different?

Tags: linux, lsof

why the result of lsof | grep pid | wc -l  and lsof -p pid |wc -l is different?

the result of `lsof -p | pid | wc -l` is similar as `ls /proc/pid/fd | wc -l`, but the result of `lsof | grep pid(or process name) |wc -l`  is big than first.

Comment: If you omit the `| wc -l` you can see what is being found in both cases and then compare the listings.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` find also find occurrences that are not pids, for instances file sizes and node numbers.

Similar for the process name, there may be file paths that contain the name of the process.